# NativeScript ./gradlew failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, nativescript, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gradlew, nativescript-cli

## Problem

On Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL), during `tns run android` command:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.
File specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.

./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Copy `platforms/android/~` directory to `platforms/android/app/~`.